# Domain Frame redirect not responsive

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So I have two Domains where one is just a domain without Webspace.

The other Domain shows to a Wordpress Installation which works fine. (www.braintwist.org)

I tried to Frame redirect the external Domain to this directory and it also works out.
(www.thebraintank.de redirected to www.braintwist.org)

The Site gets loaded in a Frameset. Unfortunatly, when I open up the site on a mobile phone the scale stays at desktop size (so the font-size is to "small" etc.)

I think its because the Frameset.

Is there a way to redirect the Domain to an external Webspace without it being loaded in a Frameset?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a small php script like this (this would need to be stored as index.php and would only redirect users accessing the index.php or the "plain" domain as URL):

```
<?php
header('Location: http://newlocation'):
?>
```

or use a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://newlocation/$1
```

or

```
Redirect / http://newlocation/
```

In the first place `mod_rewrite` must be loaded and for the second .htaccess example you need `mod_alias`.

However, in both cases you will see the new URL in the address bar of the browser.

In order to keep the URL on the addressbar you could use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://newlocation/$1 [P]
```

to proxy requests. This, however, requires `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy` to be loaded (and might cause some slower performance as all requests are done "twice" in background).

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ for `mod_rewrite` documentation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast comment :)
I changed it from Frame Redirect to Proxy Redirect and it works...the URL stays the same what I didn't thought.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .php document and upload it to your hosting. Don't create a frame forward in your domain setting, but point the domain to the created .php document. Then use the following code in your .php document to create the frame forward there.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum- 
scale=1.0; user-scalable=0">
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
</head>
<frameset rows="100%" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
<frame name="main" src="https://your-target-domain.com/" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" 
noresize="noresize">
</frameset>
<noframes>
</noframes>
</html>
```

I created a link to a favicon as well. You can take this line out if you dont need it. If you need it, simply upload your favicon as "favicon.ico" into the same directory as the .php file.

Now you have a mobile responsive frame forwarding :)